# Two video overlays another with FFMPEG

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

I'm a new user of FFmpeg, and I want to insert a logo on two videos (one video overlay another) with one command.

1. FFmpeg command (ok):
   [image]

   ```
   ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i background.mp4 -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]scale=1280:720[inner];[0][inner]overlay=70:70:shortest=1[vid];[vid][2]overlay=10:10:enable='not(between(t\,10\,15))'[out]" -map "[out]" -c:a copy -y -shortest output.mp4
   ```
2. I want to insert one (greenvideo.mp4) overlay another video Main and Background.

   [image]
3. Video (greenvideo.mp4) and video (Background.mp4): Two videos are repeated by the main video length time.
   The green video over the background.

   ```
   ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i green.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]colorkey=0x00ff00:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -shortest output.mp4
   ```

Please help me combine the above two code snippets into one?

Comment: What's the exact problem here? I'm not following your picture and what e.g. MC Green is. Formulate a question that asks specifically for the problematic aspect, "please help me?" is not a real question.

Comment: I want to combine 2 above code into 1. MC Green is the name of the video file Green.mp4

Comment: Edit the question whenever you add more details. What did you attempt?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the scale and colorkey filters before overlaying.
You can then overlay multiple times, if required, in a single script.
The basic concept is shown below.

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i mainvideo.mp4 -i greenvideo.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex /

[1]scale[SC];[2]colorkey[CK]; /

[0][SC]overlay[OVa];[OVa][CK]overlay[OVb];[OVb][3]overlay out.mp4
```

Comment: you are missing 1 input file greenvideo.mp4

Comment: Your original question is a bit confusing. I now realise the "subscribe" image is your logo. Basic principle is the same, but I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks you @Sark